# Arena Simulation Batch by condition

Tags: arena-simulation

Problem: I have a main assembly line with X number of stations. Each X station requires certain parts, without these parts the process can not be done. I am trying to simulate these parts coming into the main assembly line modeling them as entities.

I have tried batching them but Arena batches by ANY entity or by attribute. I want to batch by condition( 1 part A, 2 part B etc..). I am wondering if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Arena, however, some other software packages have a "collect" construct, versus using batch.

The main line with stations "X" carries the master parts flowing through the system.  The parts on the main line carry an identification attribute.

Parts added to the main work item flow to the line by separate queues, conveyors, storage items.

In station X12, for example-- or just before-- depending on availability of logic, the main part type attribute is assessed, then:

If main part type attribute is "A", 
collect 2 from queue/storage/etc. #1, 
collect 0 from queue #2, 
collect 1 from queue #3, 
then assemble, or not if parts travel together un-assembled.

elif part type attribute is "B"
collect 0 from queue/storage #1
collect 2 from queue #2
collect 3 from queue #3....
and so on, for the different main part types.